# Is there a better way to loop code?

Tags: python, loops, time

I am teaching myself python and I am trying to a code to open the cd drive at a certain time. For reasons of testing I have been using time.clock() because it only uses numbers, but I want to use time.ctime() so that the program will work at a specific time. This is the code that I have so far.

```
import time
import ctypes
if(time.clock()==10):
    ctypes.windll.winmm.mciSendStringW("set cdaudio door open",
            None, 0, None)
for x in range(10**100):
    print(x)
    if(20>time.clock()>10):
        ctypes.windll.winmm.mciSendStringW("set cdaudio door open",
            None, 0, None)
        quit()
```

I am using the print(x) function to monitor the code, and I set the range high enough that it won't stop before reaching the number of seconds the door should to open.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `for x in range(10**100):` you could use

```
while True:
    # do stuff forever
```

This loop will continue until you explicitly `break` out (or return for a function, raise an exception or quit the program etc).

`time.ctime()` returns a string, which is not good for comparing to a given time. Instead, I would suggest using the [datetime](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html) module

```
go_time = datetime.datetime(2014, 9, 3, 12, 30)
while True:
    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    if now >= go_time:
        # open the draw etc...
        quit()
```